# Image loading in network but not show up Github pages

Tags: html, git, image, github

Got an issue with images on Github pages. The images are showing 200 code in the network tab, but it does not show up on the page.

[image: image loading in network]

**Here is the preview**
[image]

**Here is the image looks like on the web page.**

[image: image on web page]

**The image did show up on my github repo**

[image: Image on Github Repo]

More infomation: These images are pushed to Github Repo from my local main branch, and I use GIT LFS to track the images. I found out if I upload the images via Github **file upload**, the problem resolved. I really want to know why it does not show up in the first place.

[image]

Below is my code for the img tag

```html
    <div class="topnav container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <img class="d-block" src="images/Logo.png" alt="">

      </div>
      <span class="italic uppercase font-bold text-gray">Quality Stainless steel flow equipment</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console? What is shown in the preview tab?

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3498

Comment: @dan1st no error in the console, the preview tab just show a corrupted image icon. I forgot to mention that I did use git LFS.

Comment: @dan1st So Github pages doesn't work with GIT LFS.

Comment: You may be able to get the raw url.